# Right padding for char array is not working in c

Tags: c, printf

I have char array of data ; i am writing it to a buffer for showing them in single line.

```
    char buffer[150] ;

    sprintf(buffer, "%-17s%-25s%-20s%-17s%s" ,  array[0],array[1], array[2],array[3],array[4]);
     //code uses buffer to add values to interface
```

Simply i want to allign them.Later i use these values for showing in interface.

What i am doing wrong here?

Note:example values of array

```
array[0] = '799234' or '799923'-1'
array[1] = '28/02/2014 08:03'
array[2] = 'CCC' or 'CC'
array[3] = '28/02/2014 18:03'
array[4] = '799234' or '79921'
```

Expected result of buffer; i want to add spaces to obtain fixed length after each array

```
799234    28/02/2014 08:03    CCC     28/02/2014 18:03   799234   
799923-1  28/02/2014 08:03    CC      28/02/2014 18:03   79921 
79921     28/02/2014 08:03    CCC     28/02/2014 18:03   799234
```

Actaul output

```
799234    28/02/2014 08:03    CCC     28/02/2014 18:03   799234   
799923-1    28/02/2014 08:03   CCC      28/02/2014 18:03   79921 
79921    28/02/2014 08:03   CCC     28/02/2014 18:03   799234
```

Comment: If you print the buffer, what's the *expected* and the *actual* output? Please edit your question to include both.

Comment: what does the array decl look like? as you have written it it should be char* array[5]; however ' is used for single characters.

Comment: @Claptrap yes; i have declared char * array[100][5]. here i simplified the code. the actaul one `for(i =0; i<100; i++) { sprintf(buffer, "%-17s%-25s%-20s%-17s%s" , array[i][0],array[i][1], array[i][2],array[i][3],array[i][4]); //code goes on}`

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://ideone.com/N0zJbW)

Comment: char * array[100][5]. is one level of indirection too much, lose the *

Answer (score 0):

it should work like, How you initialize array with those string? You can not assign string using single quote `''` use double `""`.

```
int main ()
{
    char *array[150];
    char buffer[150];

    array[0] = "799234";
    array[1] = "28/02/2014 08:03";
    array[2] = "CCC";
    array[3] = "28/02/2014 18:03";
    array[4] = "799234";
    sprintf(buffer, "%-17s%-25s%-20s%-17s%s" ,  array[0],array[1], array[2],array[3],array[4]);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    array[0] = "799923-1";
    array[1] = "28/02/2014 08:03";
    array[2] = "CCC";
    array[3] = "28/02/2014 18:03";
    array[4] = "79921";
    sprintf(buffer, "%-17s%-25s%-20s%-17s%s" ,  array[0],array[1], array[2],array[3],array[4]);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    array[0] = "79921";
    array[1] = "28/02/2014 08:03";
    array[2] = "CCC";
    array[3] = "28/02/2014 18:03";
    array[4] = "799234";
    sprintf(buffer, "%-17s%-25s%-20s%-17s%s" ,  array[0],array[1], array[2],array[3],array[4]);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
799234           28/02/2014 08:03         CCC                 28/02/2014 18:03 799234
799923-1         28/02/2014 08:03         CCC                 28/02/2014 18:03 79921
79921            28/02/2014 08:03         CCC                 28/02/2014 18:03 799234
```

Also here `char *array[150]` is for example. what is your type?

Comment: i have declared char * array[100][5]. here i simplified the code. The actaul one `for(i =0; i<100; i++) { sprintf(buffer, "%-17s%-25s%-20s%-17s%s" , array[i][0],array[i][1], array[i][2],array[i][3],array[i][4]); //code goes on}`

Comment: `char * array[100][5]` how you assign value to that? means it won't compile because if try to assigning type ‘char *[5]’ from type ‘char *’

Comment: i dont have problem in assiging values; Code complies and produce the result as i indicated above. What i want is if               array[0] = "799234"  , i want to add 11 spaces.                   array[0] = "799234-1", i want to add 9 spaces. Thats y i have tryed "%-17s" to obtain fixed length of  17 char. But it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

What is `array`? `array[0]` is the first element of the `array`. I would write:

```
char arr0[] = "799234";
char arr1[] = "28/02/2014 08:03";
char arr2[] = "CCC"; 
char arr3[] = "28/02/2014 18:03";
char arr4[] = "799234";
```